# R Shiny Sortable CSS: Apply different class to labels within the same bucket_list

Tags: css, r, shiny, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to maintain the colour of a given label (e.g "Blue" = blue colour; "Green" = green colour) regardless of the `bucekt_list` in which it resides. However, I have only been able to modify the CSS for a given `bucket_list` rather than to individual labels themselves. Therefore, the labels do not maintain their respective colours when dragged into a different `bucket_list` currently.

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style( HTML(".green-sortable .rank-list-item {
      background-color: #53C1BE;
      }"),
      HTML(".blue-sortable .rank-list-item {
      background-color: #4080C9;
      }")),
  fluidRow(column(6, uiOutput("example1")),
           column(6,  uiOutput("example2")))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = NULL,
      group_name = "colours",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "green-sortable"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = " ",
        input_id = "green",
        labels = "Green"
      ))
  })
  
  
  output$example2 <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = NULL,
      group_name = "colours",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "blue-sortable"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = " ",
        input_id = "blue",
        labels = "Blue"
      ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How could this be modified to as to have the blue and green labels remain blue and green in colour, respectively, regardless of the `bucket_list` into which they have been dragged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the element via a html tag (wrapped in a list) rather than a pure character. In the latter case, `sortable` will style the elemnt for you and you would need to go through some JS pain, to re-style it. Hence, it is easier to control the element yourself.

However, since your element is still placed in an outer `<div>` with some styling (most notably a `padding`) you need some extra `css` to get to a similiar look and feel.

```r
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style( HTML("#green {
      background-color: #53C1BE;
      }
      .default-sortable .rank-list-container .rank-list-item {
         padding: 0;
      }
      .rank-list-item > div {
         line-height:42px;
      }
      #blue {
         background-color: #4080C9;
      }")),
  fluidRow(column(6, uiOutput("example1")),
           column(6,  uiOutput("example2")))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = NULL,
      group_name = "colours",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "green-sortable"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = " ",
        input_id = "green",
        labels = list(div("Green", id = "green")) ## define your element yourself
      ))
  })
  
  
  output$example2 <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = NULL,
      group_name = "colours",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "blue-sortable"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = " ",
        input_id = "blue",
        labels = list(div("Blue", id = "blue")) ## define your element yourself
      ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Element keeps its own color]